# Python palindrome program

Tags: python, palindrome

I have written a palindrome program. And I was just wondering if it correct? I checked using the words racecar and madam, and it says they are palindromes. I have also tested nonpalindrome words and it worked correctly.

Is my implementation correct? If it's not could you correct it for me. It it works correct, is there an easier way to implement this?

```
def is_palindrome(x):

    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x = x.lower()
        if x[i::1] == x[::-1]:
            return("%s Is a palindrome" %(x))
        else:
            return("%s Is not a palindrome" %(x))

print(is_palindrome('racecar'))
```

Answer (score 9):

I would expect a function that has a "predicate" name (`is_x()`) to return a boolean value rather than a string.  The boolean is much more useful to the caller.

We should add a main-guard to top-level code, so the file could be useful as a module.

Consider adding some unit tests.  A convenient way to do this is using the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html) module, which finds tests in the function's docstring; any line beginning with `>>>` is a test, and is immediately followed by the expected result.

Building on [the version shown by C.Nivs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236366/75307), that would give this improved version:

```
def is_palindrome(x):
    '''
    True if the letters of x are the same when
    reversed, ignoring differences of case.
    >>> is_palindrome('')
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('a')
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('a0')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('ab')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('ab a')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('Aba')
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('Àbà')
    True
    '''
    x = x.lower()
    # Alternative (letters only):
    #     x = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, x.lower()))
    # Alternative (letters and digits only):
    #     x = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum x.lower()))
    return x[::-1] == x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    for string in sys.argv[1:]:
        # check each command-line argument
        message = 'is a palindrome' if is_palindrome(string) else 'is not a palindrome'
        print(f'{string} {message}')
    else:
        # no arguments, so run self-test
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
```

It may well make sense to separate the pre-processing from the palindrome checking, so that `is_palindrome()` simply returns `x[::-1] == x`, and the caller is responsible for deciding which characters are significant.  We could call it with a specific canonicalisation:

```
is_palindrome(string.lower())
```

More advanced would be to pass a normalisation function and/or a character filter, as optional arguments:

```
def is_palindrome(s, normalise=None, char_filter=None):
    '''
    True if the letters of x are the same when
    reversed, ignoring differences of case.
    >>> is_palindrome('')
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('a')
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('a0')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('a0', char_filter=str.isalpha)
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('ab')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('ab a')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('Aba')
    False
    >>> is_palindrome('Aba', normalise=str.lower)
    True
    >>> is_palindrome('Àbà', normalise=str.lower)
    True
    '''
    if normalise:
        s = normalise(s)
    if char_filter:
        s = ''.join(filter(char_filter, s))
    return s == ''.join(reversed(s))
```

Usage of these optional arguments should be apparent from the extra tests I've added.

---

### Bug

Whether we use `[::-1]` or `reversed()` to reverse the input string, we have a bug when the input contains characters that are formed using combining accents, as demonstrated by these additional tests:

```
>>> is_palindrome("o̅o") # o+overline, o
False
>>> is_palindrome("o̅o̅") # o+overline, o+overline
True
```

Both of these fail, because we reverse the string by treating each Unicode character independently, rather than considering them as (possibly multi-character) letters.  To fix that, we'll need to find or create a combining-character-aware function to reverse a string - I'm not aware of such a thing in the Python standard library.

Comment: Yeah im a beginner if you can't already tell lol but I mean the program is still working and putting out positive results but I guess I need to make it more clearer and organized

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the loop. Once `i > 0`, the `if` statement will always be `False`:

```py
x = 'abba'
x[0::1] == x[::-1]
True

x[1::1] == x[::-1]
False

x[1::1]
'bba'
```

So drop the iteration. Besides, the immediate `return` won't allow for iteration anyways, a second iteration will never be reached:

```py
def is_palindrome(x):
    x = x.lower()

    if x[::-1] == x:
        return f'{x} is a palindrome'
    else:
        return f'{x} is not a palindrome'
```

You don't need the parentheses with `return`, and I'd use f-strings instead of `%` formatting if you're on python 3.5+.

If you are adding the possibilities of spaces/punctuation, you could change `x` to only include alphabet chars:

```py
def is_palindrome(x):
    # this will produce only alphabet lowercase chars
    # and join them into a string, though I'm not sure if
    # this is a use case for you
    x = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, x.lower()))

    if x[::-1] == x:
        return f'{x} is a palindrome'
    else:
        return f'{x} is not a palindrome'
```

To show what that join statement does:

```py
# maybe this should be a palindrome if you ignore the
# non-alpha chars including spaces
x = "ABC1234CB a."

y = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, x.lower()))
'abccba'
```

### Edit

To address concerns in the comments, if you wanted to offer options into what kind of filtering you want to provide, you could use a dictionary to act as a mapping:

```py
from functools import partial

def is_palindrome(input_str, filter_type='nofilter'):
   """
   Parameter 'filter_type' defaults to pass-through, but you can
   provide options such as 'alphanum', 'nospace' (to just get rid of spaces), and 'alpha'
   """
   filters = {
       'alpha': partial(filter, str.isalpha),
       'alphanum': partial(filter, str.isalnum),
       'nospace': partial(filter, lambda char: not char.isspace()),
       'nofilter': partial(map, lambda char: char) # this is just a pass-through 
   }

   # raise this exception just so the use is more clear to the user
   # what is expected
   try:
       f = filters[filter_type]
   except KeyError as e:
       raise ValueError(
           f"Invalid filter_type, choose one of {'\n'.join(filters)}"
       ) from e

   x = ''.join(filter_type(input_str.lower()))

   # you can just check the first half of the string
   # against the last half reversed, rather than comparing the entire string 
   midpoint = len(x) // 2
   if len(x) % 2: # even length
       a = b = midpoint
   else:
       a, b = midpoint + 1, midpoint

   return x[:a] == x[b::-1]
```

[`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) will bind arguments to a function and return a new callable. As a small example:

```py
def f(a):
    return a

g = partial(f, 1)
f(2)
2

g()
1
```

Which is helpful for taking a function that takes many arguments and returning one that takes fewer arguments.

Credit to [Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236367/185198) for returning `bool` type, @Baldrickk for midpoint slice, and @Peilonrayz for concern over input filtering.

Comment: Why have you added `str.isalpha`?  0w0 is a palindrome, not because you mutilate it to become w.

Comment: @Peilonrayz sure, that didn't appear to be OP's use case. I didn't see any clarification from OP that this needed to be the case, and I don't see how it makes the review wrong. I also mentioned that OP *could* have this option, but it's not necessary

Comment: @Peilonrayz it could easily be made to be alphanumeric, which would make sense, but it _does_ show the method by which would be done, so I wouldn't fault the answer for this.

Comment: An additional note - you don't need to compare the full string `x` with its reverse - you need only compare the first half with the reverse of the second half.

Comment: @Baldrickk And why o' why would I ever want my `is_palindrome` to mangle my input? Not only does it violate SRP, it makes absolutely no sense for it to be there. If you want to check if only the alpha is a palindrome, then make a `filter_to_alpha` function and use `is_palindrome(filter_to_alpha(value))`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I made an edit to more clearly outline options OP could use. Again, a lot of this starts to just turn into personal taste based on how the code is supposed to be used, but hopefully this is a bit more clear

Comment: @Baldrickk the midpoint slice suggestion is a really good one for longer strings, thanks

Comment: To be clear, this is continuing to violating SRP in the same way.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Maybe so, but if I don't include that, does that make the review bad? Normally I'm not one to argue with suggestions, but a review does not have to cover every facet of code. Do I need to cover code down to the nth possible standard for it to be correct? I don't see that outlined in [How to Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: "does that make the review bad?" To me; when an answer add a problem that the OP didn't - yes.

Comment: @Peilonrayz palindromes as defined in a language basis only involve the letters.  For example, "Don’t nod." is a palindrome, despite being different to ".don t'noD".  Therefore a palindrome checker is expected to make the conversion.  If you were writing up formal requirements, that would be one.  Mangling input is done all the time - if I want a phone number off you, I don't care if you write `01234 567 890` or `01234567890` or `0123 45 67 890` - all I care about is the data that represents - the presentation of that is separate. palindromes are about the characters, so that's what you test.

Comment: @Peilonrayz if you want to implement it as a pair of functions, then that's fine, but the principle of least astonishment would be to provide the defined correct answer to `is_palindrome(value)` and not have to call `is_palindrome(filter_to_alpha(value))` to get the correct result.

Comment: @Baldrickk I was rather astonished when I saw the normalization. So, to me, it violates that too.